# Test if my array is nil at a given index?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I'm trying to create an `NSMutableArray` containing the contents of another at a given index.

I'm initializing the new array with `initWithArray:` if the previous array has anything at the index, otherwise with plain `init`

This code doesn't work but you should be able to get the idea from it:

```
NSMutableArray *typeCourseCutId;
if([self.typeCourseCut objectAtIndex:typeCourseIndex] != nil){
    typeCourseCutId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.typeCourseCut objectAtIndex:typeCourseIndex]];
} else {
    typeCourseCutId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Is there a solution for this kind of test?

Comment: Which type of data store in Self.typeCourseCut?

Comment: `objectAtIndex:` will never return `nil` for _any_ index. Cocoa arrays can't contain `nil`, and if you try to access an index outside the array's bounds, an exception will be raised. Trying to put `nil` into an array will also cause an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the count of the array. If the count is greater than the index you are fetching, then it means that an object is present at that index.

Also make sure your `self.typeCourseCut` is an array of `NSArray` objects, otherwise your `initWithArray:` will crash.

Also you can add an empty object to an array as `[yourArray addObject:[NSNull null]];`
And most importantly, without having an object at index 1, you cannot add an object to index 2.

Comment: This is the correct answer; if the index is in the correct range, there's an object there. The note about `initWithArray:` is also important.

Comment: Thank you, i did though about this [... count] option, but didn't go thru... i'll try to get an update on the NSNull doc from Apple.

Answer (score 6):

There is a special class called [`NSNull`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that is created specifically to use as null indicator in collections:

> The `NSNull` class defines a singleton object used to represent `null` values in collection objects (which don’t allow `nil` values).

```
if([self.typeCourseCut objectAtIndex:typeCourseIndex] != [NSNull null]) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

An array should not be nil at any index. the way an array is built is that as soon as it reaches a nil object. it is considered the end of the array.

You cannot add a nil object nor can you update an existing object to nil.

If you must set something to a "Null" style object you can use NSNull in its place. THis is what most of the JSON parsers do for objects that they want to show up, but be null.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help

```
   if([array objectAtIndex:0] != [NSNull null])
    {
       NSLog(@"INDEX 0);
    }
    else if([array objectAtIndex:1] != [NSNull null])
    {
         NSLog(@"INDEX 1);
    }
    else if([array objectAtIndex:2] != [NSNull null])
    {
         NSLog(@"INDEX 2);
    }
```